# Audio component in Javascript with Vue3

Tags: javascript, audio, vuejs3

I am trying to make a component in Vue3 to manage audio. This component will display a button that when pressed, plays an audio (just a short word) and changes the color (to show it is playing the audio).

Currently I managed to play the audio, but I have some issues that I am not sure how to resolve, which arise because I don't really understand how the Audio object works in javascript:

1. The class `.playing` is never applied to the element (isPlaying always returns false!)
2. How can I check the audio gets loaded before playing it? In case the URL is not reachable the `.play()` call should not be executed. But I am not sure `canplaythrough` event will work for me, since I just want to load the audio once (and only if the user presses the button).
3. What is the proper way of managing events for `new Audio()`? Try catch or I can do something with promises?
4. How to unmount this component correctly? `this.audio.pause(); this.audio.src = null`?

```
<template>
<button v-on:click="play" :class="{playing: isPlaying}">Audio</button>
</template>
<script>
export default {
    name: 'AudioComponent',
    data() {
        return {
            audio: null,
        }
    },
    props: {
        url: {type: String, required: true}
    },
    computed: {
        isPlaying(){
            if(this.audio !== null){
                if(!this.audio.paused && this.audio.duration > 0){
                    return true;
                }
            }
            return false;
        }
    },
    methods: {
        play(){
            if(this.audio === null){
                this.audio = new Audio(this.url);
            }
            this.audio.play();
        }
    }
}
</script>
<style scoped>
.playing {
    color: green;
}
</style>
```

Note that this is a simplification of the code, but should be enough to see the issue. Since I couldn't find many examples using `new Audio` call I am wondering if I should use the DOM calls directly instead.

Note that I am using the options API but don't mind answers with composition API too.

Comment: `isPlaying` is never defined in your code.

Comment: Thanks for noticing, it was defined but lost when porting the code to stackoverflow.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. `this.audio` properties are not reactive, so [`HTMLMediaElement` events](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/HTMLMediaElement#events) `play` and `pause` must be used.
2. Yes, using the `canplay` event.
3. You can listen for the `error` event as well, if that's your question.
4. I don't think you need to do anything in particular.

[Demo](https://jsfiddle.net/r7a59e42/)

```js
{
    props: {
        url: {
            type: String,
            default: 'https://samplelib.com/lib/preview/mp3/sample-3s.mp3'
        }
    },
    data: () => ({
        audio: null,
        canPlay: false,
        isPlaying: false
    }),
    methods: {
        play: async function(){
            this.audio.play();
        }
    },
    mounted: function(){
        this.audio = new Audio(this.url);
        this.audio.addEventListener('canplay', () => this.canPlay = true, { once: true });
        this.audio.addEventListener('play', () => this.isPlaying = true);
        this.audio.addEventListener('pause', () => this.isPlaying = false);
        this.$watch(() => this.audio.duration, () => console.log(this.audio.paused));
    },
    template: `
        <button
            :class="{ playing: isPlaying }"
            :disabled="!canPlay"
            @click="play"
        >Audio</button>
    `
}
```

Comment: Thanks, this is more or less what I was looking for. One quick addition, if it is needed to check for errors (like network error, or file not found) another event listener can be added:
`this.audio.addEventListener('error', () => console.error('could not load audio file'));`

Comment: You're welcome. Just like I said in reply to question no. 3, yes.